# Join using case statement

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
 tbl_cid
-------------------------
| cid | sid | rid | dt  |
-------------------------
| 1   | 101 | 103 | xxx |
| 6   | 104 | 101 | xxx |
| 8   | 104 | 103 | xxx |
| 9   | 105 | 104 | xxx |
-------------------------

tbl_uid
--------------
| uid | name |
--------------
| 101 | john |
| 103 | tim  |
| 104 | paul |
| 105 | alex |
--------------

SELECT u.name, c.cid, c.sid, c.rid FROM tbl_cid c
JOIN tbl_uid u on u.uid = c.sid 
WHERE c.sid = 101 OR c.rid = 101

Expected result:
--------------------
| cid | uid | name |
--------------------
| 1   | 103 | tim  |
| 6   | 104 | paul |
--------------------
```

I have tried it in different ways but could not find it out. 
Say if i am searching for 101 in `tbl_cid` if sid has 101 then join rid if rid has 101 then join sid. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually disagree with @wdika, you should use joins because using a where clause with two tables just does the joins implicitly.

```
SELECT u.name, c.cid, c.sid, c.rid FROM tbl_cid c
    JOIN tbl_uid u on u.uid = c.sid or u.uid = c.rid
    WHERE (c.sid = 101 OR c.rid = 101) and u.uid != 101;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
select tbl_cid.cid, tbl_uid.uid, tbl_uid.name
from tbl_cid, tbl_uid
where (tbl_cid.sid = tbl_uid.uid AND tbl_cid.rid = 101) OR (tbl_cid.rid = tbl_uid.uid AND tbl_cid.sid = 101);

Result:
--------------------
| cid | uid | name |
--------------------
| 1   | 103 | tim  |
| 6   | 104 | paul |
--------------------
```

Comment: Or, using `INNER JOIN` you could do `select cid,uid,name from tbl_cid
INNER JOIN tbl_uid ON
sid=101 AND uid=rid OR rid=101 AND uid=sid`